# Return the index of the user's selected table with the MS Word VBA Tables collection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to build a macro that performs operations on the table the user placed their cursor in.  How do I determine which index within the table collection the table corresponds to?

Answer (score 4):

The following example finds the index

```
Dim tabnum
tabnum = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.Count
MsgBox tabnum
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is to the originally asked question, below, that was later edited by the OP so that his self-answer fit the question:

> I need to build a macro that performs operations on the table the user
>   placed their cursor in. How do I determine which index within the
>   table collection the table corresponds to?

If all you want is to work with the table in which the current selection is, you don't need to know the index of the table in the document:

```
Dim tbl as Word.Table
Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
'Now continue to work with the tbl object
```

Comment: True, if that's all you need to do.  The question was poorly framed.

Comment: Yes, and it's poor form to change a question after-the-fact to invalidate Answers already posted.

Comment: Thanks for the etiquette heads up.